# "Stack overflow during evaluation" with stdlib List.map

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml, tail-recursion

Say I have a bunch of ones:

```
Array.make (int_of_float (2. ** 17.)) 1
    |> Array.to_list;;
- : int list
= [1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1;
   1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1;
   1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1;
   1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1;
   1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1;
   1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1;
   1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1;
   1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1;
   1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1;
   1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1;
   1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1;
   1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; ...]
```

And I want to map a function over these ones:

```
Array.make (int_of_float (2. ** 17.)) 1
    |> Array.to_list
    |> List.map (fun x -> x * 2);;
Stack overflow during evaluation (looping recursion?).
```

Seems like it's too much!  Looking into how List.map is implemented in Ocaml, I find this
(https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/blob/trunk/stdlib/list.ml#L57-L59):

```
let rec map f = function
    [] -> []
  | a::l -> let r = f a in r :: map f l
```

I'm pretty new to Ocaml, but it looks like map is written in a way that makes it not tail-recursive.

Is that right?

How do I map a function over lots of stuff?

Comment: Out of pure curiosity, why do you want to write that code in the first place?

Comment: The code is to illustrate the smallest example of my problem.  This is a part of a much larger body of work that fails on large inputs.

Comment: It is more than probable that your code could be done without a map, like for instance generating the list after the series of calculations.

Comment: Sure, but then what stores that series and how do I map my calculations over it?

Comment: @Conrad.Dean: As @PatJ suggests, you may not want that fully materialized list of intermediate results anyway, if you're going to `map` away from it again. A slightly more complex alternative is [Rich Hickey's notion of *transducers*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6mTbuzafcII) [StrangeLoop tech talk on YouTube].

Comment: Oh okay so instead of generating my starter values and going from there, formulating the problem so i know what the `i` th element would be in the entire pipeline to avoid this problem in `List.map`.

Comment: @Conrad.Dean exactly! You can also try lazy evaluation and/or streams if you want more control on your evaluation order while keeping low memory consumption.

Comment: @PatJ yeah, i haven't run into this problem before in other languages so that's what this surprised me.  Guess different languages are different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, `List.map` in OCaml Standard Library is not tail-recursive. You have several options here:

1. Use `Array.map`
2. Use `List.rev_map` (possibly coined with `List.rev`)
3. Use some other data structure that is more suitable to your task
4. Don't use standard library

While the first two options are obvious, the latter two need some explanation.

### Better data structure

If you really have a big amount of data, and if this data is numerical, then you should consider using Bigarrays. Also, depending on you use case, Maps and Hashtables might be better. People in functional programming languages tend to use lists everywhere, instead of choosing a proper data structure. Don't step into this pitfall.

### Other libraries and why it is non tail recursive

The `List.map` is non tail recursive for a good reason. There is always a tradeoff between stack usage and performance. For small lists (and this is the most common use case) a non-tail recursive version is much faster. So the standard library decided to provide a fast `List.map` and in case if you need to work on big lists then you can use `List.rev_map xs |> List.rev`. Moreover, sometimes you can omit the `List.rev` part. So, the standard library, is not trying to think for you, it gives you a choice.

On the other hand, with time people managed to find some optimum in this tradeoff, i.e., having a constant stack version which is quite fast. The solution is to use a non tail recursive approach when a list is small, and then fallback to a slow version. Such implementations are provided by [Janestreet Core Library](https://github.com/janestreet/core), [Batteries](http://batteries.forge.ocamlcore.org/) and [Containers](https://github.com/c-cube/ocaml-containers/) library.

So, you can switch to those libraries and forget about this issue. Though it is still highly advised to use `List.map` scarcely and with care, as this operation is always has linear memory consumption (either heap or stack memory), that can be avoided. So, it is better to use `rev_map` whenever it is possible.

Comment: I'm really new to Ocaml and I keep seeing these competing libraries that are trying to be the Real stdlib.  What's the cause of that? Why does the core language seem to require all the addons?

Comment: Well, C and C++ are also useless without addon libraries (and these two languages cover the majority of programming space, so we can say that this is a common situation). There're languages like python and java, that comes with batteries installed, but they are backed by a serious man-power. I think that INRIA has excellent scientists, whose talents can be spent on something more interesting than supporting the library. So they provided a minimal algrebra as a foundation on top of which we can build our software. And `opam` makes it easy to combine them into a platform, similar to .NET.

Answer (score 3):

You are correct List.map is not tail recursive , use List.rev_map instead which is tail recursive. ... And List.rev that should be tail recursive.

[List](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/List.html) documents all the function of List module, indicating whether it is not tail recursive.

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is construct the list at the end of your calculation:

```
let construct_value _ =
 1 |> (fun x -> x * 2)

let rec construct_list f n =
 let rec aux acc n =
  if n < 0
  then acc
  else aux (f n) (n-1)
 in
 aux [] (n-1)

let result = construct_list construct_value (int_of_float (2. ** 17.))
```

Here you end up with the same list as in your calculations, but with way less time and memory usage. Note that the elements of the list are constructed from the bottom of the list (you have to do it for tail-recursion), I added an "index" parameter that corresponds to the exact position in your array (that I did not construct, another time and memory gain)

Also, if you want to do calculations on that big of a data structure, lists are probably not the best option, but that depends on what you intend to do with it after.